# View ongoing Alembic cache in Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel, alembic-format

So for example, I am caching using Alembics a mesh for 1000 frames and at 500 frames of it, I want to be able to view it in Maya. I know that if I import that ongoing alembic it does not show anything in the viewport and errors out.

```
# Error: path.abc is not a valid Alembic file
```

Is there a way I can view it in Maya while it's still caching?